# How can I implement a filter that inverts colors?

Tags: dart, flutter

Suppose I want to invert the RGB colors on a widget to produce a "negative" feel, what should I do to achieve that?

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is that Flutter doesn't support this as far as I know.

Theoretically, if it were to support it, you would use a [ShaderMask](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/ShaderMask-class.html) and simply pass it the corresponding `Shader` such as InvertColorShader, but there is no shader that does an invert for now.

You could ask for one to be added by creating a bug in the Flutter repository and they might consider it if you describe a convincing use-case.