# How to invert image color in Flutter?

Tags: flutter

How I can invert programmatically the color of an image in flutter?
I want to invert the full color of the image not only the background.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

now it's possible using the `ColorFiltered` widget.

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-ui/ColorFilter-class.html

You find a detailed explanation on my blog
https://www.burkharts.net/apps/blog/over-the-rainbow-colour-filters/

Comment: decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    image: DecorationImage(
                      image: AssetImage('images/africa.png'),
                      fit: BoxFit.contain,
                      invertColors: true, //This works too
                    ),
                  ),

Answer (score 5):

For flutter you can do the following with ColorFilter:

```dart
ColorFiltered(
  colorFilter: invertImage
    ? const ColorFilter.matrix(<double>[
        -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 255.0, //
        0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 255.0, //
        0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 255.0, //
        0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, //
      ])
    : const ColorFilter.matrix(<double>[
        1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, //
        0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, //
        0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, //
        0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, //
      ]),
   child: Image(...),
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Currently it's not possible to invert colors with *out of the box* solutions. You can try to use [ShaderMask](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/ShaderMask-class.html) as suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49986484/how-can-i-implement-a-filter-that-inverts-colors). You may also check out [BlendMode](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/dart-ui/BlendMode-class.html) options.

Answer (score 1):

You can use my package [invert_colors](https://pub.dev/packages/invert_colors), and wrap any widget in it:

```
InvertColors(child: YourWidget());
```

This will invert the colors of any of its children.

Comment: the package doesn't support null safety

Answer (score 1):

I tried this solution:
wrap the image with `MediQuery` widget then provide a copy of `MediaQuery.of(contxt)` to the `data` property..

```
MediaQuery(
  data: MediaQuery.of(context).copyWith(invertColors: true),
  child: Image.asset("image_path_here"),
)
```

Original:

[image: original]

Inverted:

[image: inverted]

Answer (score 0):

if you want to stick to cpu color space without render logic you can use

```
 final colorRaw = Theme.of(context).colorScheme.primary;
final invertColor = colorRaw.withBlue(1 - colorRaw.blue).withGreen(1 - colorRaw.green).withRed(1- colorRaw.red);
```