# How can I apply a filter on a PNG image so that it can be displayed in light mode and dark mode in flutter?

Tags: flutter, image

My app displays transparent PNG images (diagrams) which have black lines and colored lines.

To minimize app storage, and efficiency, I am seeking for the same PNG image to be able to be displayed in both dark and light mode. In light mode, the PNG already displays correctly on a white background. But when the app is in dark mode, (with a dark background), I want the black lines only to turn white. I imagined this might be possible with a color filter, but I can't get it quite working.

I can get close to it as the attached images shows for example, but I need to lose the black background, or lose the colored lines.

Is this possible with a filter or is there another workaround to this?

```
                  Image.network(image,
                    colorBlendMode: BlendMode.color,
                    color: Colors.white,
                  ),
```

[image: example image]

/// with these properties   color: Colors.black,colorBlendMode: BlendMode.difference,
[image: example image 2]

/// with these properties  color: Colors.white,colorBlendMode: BlendMode.color, (background turns white and lose the blue color)
[image: image 3]

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56107197/how-to-invert-image-color-in-flutter

Comment: Thank you very much! This is very helpful. I have applied ColorFilter.matrix and input values to create an inverse effect as per the post answers. Although I havent quite worked out how to keep blue as is (can change to other colors), the black lines turn white, so on the right path now. Cheers.